# How to increase executionTimeout

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

i have two application .net web api (version 4.7.1)
the first app call some api from second app
i want to increase timeout to 5 min
i add **executionTimeout** to the first app, but dosn't work
this is the web config  of my first app :

```html
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" executionTimeout="300" />
  </system.web>
```

**i test just with 2 sec** 
i don't know why dosn't work !

x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x

how i call the socond app :

```js
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TestResponseOfAccountViewModel> GetAllAccountsAsync(string pClientId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Account/GetAllAccounts");

            var client_ = await CreateHttpClientAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    var content_ = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pClientId, _settings.Value));
                    content_.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                    request_.Content = content_;
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("POST");
                    request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);

                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }

                        ProcessResponse(client_, response_);

                        var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                        if (status_ == "200")
                        {
                            var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<TestResponseOfAccountViewModel>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            return objectResponse_.Object;
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ != "200" && status_ != "204")
                        {
                            var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            throw new EngineException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + (int)response_.StatusCode + ").", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, null);
                        }

                        return default(TestResponseOfAccountViewModel);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (response_ != null)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (client_ != null)
                    client_.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what exactly still throwing the timeout exception maybe the call to the second app not the first app it self.. can you add the exception and example of the call you are doing

Comment: the some thing, i add to my question i test with **2sec**

Comment: can you post the exception ..

Comment: i have no exception, for testing a add a **await Task.Delay(2000);** in my second app

Comment: and how do you call app 2 from app 1? HtppClient or RestSharp or ........ the more code you most the easiest will make it for us to help u :)

Comment: i use swagger to connect to the socond app

Comment: this calls also have timeouts so provide the code how you are implementing it

Comment: look my edit please

Comment: can you try to set the timeout property for the client also ?

Comment: do you mean the first app, if yes, yes i can do it

Comment: yes... so that it doesnt throw timeout in the connection

Comment: i add timeout when a call my second app,** httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);** thanks a lot

Comment: Ok I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple timeouts you have set one of them in the web.config but there is also another timeout to be set when you make HTTP Requests / Connections to DB for example. In your case you need to set the timeout in the **HttpClient** returned from **CreateHttpClientAsync** for example :

`client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)`

to increase the timeout in the second app call